# option in one set of checkbox has to be kept as default when clicking an option in another set of check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two set of check boxes. When I am selecting the check box with id radio14 (in set one), I would like to have checkbox with id radio12 to be checked as default automatically.

```js
var chk1 = document.getElementById("#radio14");
var chk2 = document.getElementById("#radio12");


chk1.onclick = function(){
  if( chk1.checked == 1 ) {
    chk2.setAttribute('checked', true);
  } else {
    chk2.setAttribute('checked', false);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="Finishing" id="radio12" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio12">Silky Matt lamination</label>

<input type="radio" name="Special_Finishing" id="radio14" class="radio"/> 
<label for="radio14">Digital Embossing </label>
```

Comment: `#foo` is CSS selector syntax, `getElementById` does not want a selector as parameter, but only the actual ID value. (And checkboxes and radio buttons are different things, btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const checkbox1 = document.getElementById('radio14');
const checkbox2 = document.getElementById('radio12');

checkbox1.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (checkbox1.checked) {
    checkbox2.setAttribute('checked', true);
  } else {
    checkbox2.setAttribute('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio12" />
<label for="radio12">Silky Matt lamination</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio14"/> 
<label for="radio14">Digital Embossing</label>
```

If you're using `getElementById` you have to pass only `id`, without `#`.